# Migrate orders from Magento 1.x to 2.x using the Magento data migration tool

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

The products, attribute sets, prices, categories, etc has been already migrated from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x. I want to migrate the orders now.

Is it possible to migrate only orders from the Magento 2 data migration tool or is there any other way to migrate the orders?

I am also thinking of mapping the `sales_flat` table of Magento 1.x to the `sales_order` table of Magento 2 and push the CSV from MySQL.

Is there any other way?

Comment: just curious: why do you not want to use the tool?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer May i know what are all steps you followed for migration of products, attribute sets, prices, categories, etc

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the `data-migration-tool` for this, and I'd recommend to do so over any other methods: it will do the necessary field value conversions where needed.

We were in a similar position as you: we imported product data (catalog, products) at an earlier point in time, then built the shop's design and functionalities and now will do a final data migration run for the customers, quotes, orders, logs and similar stuff.

In the `config.xml`, comment out the substeps you do not want to run again. in my case, I have the following disabled:

- settings: everything
- data: eav step, url rewrite step,  configurable prices step, tier price step, post processing step
- in `map.xml`, I made sure to ignore all tables that I do not want the data to be migrated for.

Be sure to include the necessary

`<ignore><document>{tablename}</document></ignore>`

in both sections (`<source>` and `<destination>` (maybe called `<target>` in older versions)).

Be sure to test the migration on a copy of your db's (both magento 1.x and magento 2.x) as it can be quite destructive. It took me a few days and tries to get the mappings adjusted to our needs, but now the migration runs through without a hick.

I was not able to get the **delta migration** properly running with the above modifications, but in most cases, you'll only want to migrate the data just once before switching the new shop live.

If your 1.x shop has a fair amount of data, the migration process will take quite a while tho. be sure to run the migration in a `screen` shell session or similar to avoid data loss due to disconnects.

Comment: Nice one. Something you can use is the wildcard character (`*`) in your ignore of documents instead of writing all of them out.

Comment: Had an issue where the customer data was not copying. But orders were.

Comment: i want to migrate orders and & customers only, for that what are all the ignore we need to add in map.xml. give me idea

Comment: So instead of teelling the tool what to DO migrate, you need to add every existing table that you DONT want to migrate? Refering to `in map.xml, I made sure to ignore all tables that I do not want the data to be migrated for.` .... what happens when a table is not defined in this document? (so it does exist, but has no entry in the xml)