# How to skip a step in magento 2 data migration?

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

Is there a way to skip the EAV step described in the [technical internals of magento 2 migration](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-tool-internal-spec.html)

Comment: Similar question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134046/migrate-orders-from-magento-1-9-to-2-using-the-magento-data-migration-tool/134326. You can just comment out some steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment out the step in your `config.xml`