# How to migrate only orders with Data Migration Tool?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, magento-2.1.3, magento2-migration-tool

I want to migrate ORDERS from magento1.

What i already achieved:

1. Migrate all data(customers,orders,products,categories,settings etc)
2. Migrate ONLY Customers

Main objective to know config steps which will migrate only orders. OR both Orders and customers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apologizes for late reply and this was FINAL solution that worked for me.

Config.xml file:

```
    <steps mode="data">
     <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
     </step>

    <step title="Map Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
     </step>
     <step title="OrderGrids Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
     </step>
     <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
     </step>
</steps>
```

Only command required:

> php bin/magento migrate:data
>   vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.1/config.xml

Map.xml: Ignore most tables that were creating issue.

User can get such issues in migration like:

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '77-10' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'

Empty these tables to fix issues. You can figure out tables name like this
(Note the initials):

> 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID' =
>   catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity

Comment: Great work stealing my answer and then choosing it as correct. A great example for building a good community. Fool.

Comment: @StevieG ... You misunderstood it. I had fixed the issues before you posted the answer though i posted answer lately. You can see fixed errors as well in my answer. I accepted my answer which BEST work for me AND that really doent mean your answer is not informative. I had already UP-VOTED your answer which means I respect your input.

Comment: @jai can you check this pls? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207220/general-question-regarding-the-data-migration-tool-of-magento#207220

Comment: Sure. I will sort out your issue.  Please allow me time by evening.

Comment: Also add all ignore lines in your map.xml from @StevieG answer.

Comment: Mismatch of entities in the document: wishlist Source: 2 Destination: 0?[0m
  [Migration\Exception]   Volume Check failed, i got the above error, what is the exact error. give me a idea to fix the issue

Comment: After trying this my 300 products got deleted and site is also messed up

Comment: after i truncate catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity table. my 300 products got deleted. Does anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 11):

For orders, you will usually need customers as well.

I used [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134046/migrate-orders-from-magento-1-9-to-2-using-the-magento-data-migration-tool/134326) when I first did this.

Only run the `bin/magento migrate:data` command. And with `-r` if you want to start from scratch.

In your `config.xml`, comment out the `Eav` and other steps you want to exclude:

```
<steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <!--<step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>-->
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <!--<step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>-->
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <!--<step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>-->
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <!--<step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>-->
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <!--<step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>-->
    </steps>
```

Then in your `map.xml` ignore most product stuff with:

```
         <ignore>
             <document>catalog_category*</document>
         </ignore>
         <ignore>
             <document>catalog_compare*</document>
         </ignore>
         <ignore>
             <document>catalog_eav_attribute</document>
         </ignore>
         <ignore>
             <document>cataloginventory_stock*</document>
         </ignore>
         <ignore>
             <document>catalog_product_*</document>
         </ignore>
         <ignore>
             <document>core_*</document>
         </ignore>
         <ignore>
             <document>cms_*</document>
         </ignore>
```

Comment: in map.xml ignore in source or destination or both?

Comment: I added both seems to work!! :)

Comment: Seems like you have to delete test customers and test order created on the M2 instance after you've done the initial migration, then this approach works! (You can delete orders with this module: https://packagist.org/packages/thecodingtutor/magento2-delete-orders )

Comment: @Stephen My some of the products get deleted  after following this step.