# General Question regarding the data migration tool of Magento

Tags: customer, data-migration, magento2.2.2

I know Magento recommends Data migration in below order:

1. Settings
2. Data
3. Changes

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate.html

First, we need to migrate the settings, then data and delta.

Suppose I need to migration customer data only from Magento 1 to Magento 2. After successfully installing and configuring the Data migration tool, is it OK to proceed with data migration avoiding the first step(settings migration)?

Magento says settings need to be done first. But my concern is i have already configured settings in Magento 2 and if i do setting migration all that i have done will gets lost!!

So what is the best possible way for me to proceed here? Please advise me those who already done data migration successfully.

P.S: I prefer default data migration tool provided by magento. I am not interested in third party tools. So please dont suggest me those in answer :)

Comment: And you no need to use any 3rd party tool. Official tool is able to complete your work. Please try migrate and post your outcome/error. Use config.xml file of my answer to import.
First, have backup of everything ie DB and code.

Comment: ok, i have managed to put your config.xml, there were so many issues with documents/fields etc and all fixed. data got migrated. However, i can see besides customer and order data, products, page and blocks are also moved. I dont know how this happened. https://prnt.sc/hsvbxy https://prnt.sc/hsvckh i didnt added products in config.xml. I am wondering how.

Comment: You need to add IGNORE to avoid importing. ie if you dont want to migrate product and realted data then you can add this in MAP.xml: 
         <ignore>
            <document>catalog_*</document>
        </ignore>
..... Same to ignore CMS pages: <ignore>
    <document>cms_*</document>
</ignore>

This is throughout process and you keep adding IGNORE to get final result.

Comment: this need to amend in source or destination? I can see its already in the source of map.xml.

Comment: Add in both locations

Comment: Okay Jai. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

You have control of what you want to migrate.

Just comment the steps you want to skip in your config.xml

e.g

```
<!--  <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>-->
```

Or in your case ignore the settings migration all together.