# Magento 2.25 customer and order migration Mismatch of entities in the document

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, data-migration

I've migrating Customer and Order from `Magento 1.9.0.1` to `Magento 2.2.5` version, for the Customer and Order migration I've reviewed the following post and implemented in my local.
[How to migrate only orders with Data Migration Tool?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173537/how-to-migrate-only-orders-with-data-migration-tool/178999#comment352132_178999)

Then I run the following command for migration purpose

```
php bin/magento migrate:data -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.0.1/config.xml
```

But I am getting following error in the command line and `migration.log` file.

In Migration.log file :
Mismatch of entities in the document: wishlist Source: 2 Destination: 0

In command line
[image]

What is the exact issue is there, how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance for you support & help

Comment: Did you got solution for this issue?