# Magento2.3.2 During data migration I got Only enties mismatch error . Only orders data in not migrated

Tags: magento2, order-grid, data-migration

My migration is from Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.3.2.
 I ran the below command :

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento migrate:data vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.1.0/config.xml
-r -vvv -a
```

It completed the migration but showing no result in the order grid only. Rest all Products and customer are shown in my M2.

> [2019-09-12 07:45:14][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document:
>   sales_order_grid Source: 37050 Destination: 0 [2019-09-12
>   07:45:14][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document:
>   sales_shipment_grid Source: 33540 Destination: 0 [2019-09-12
>   07:45:14][WARNING]: Volume Check failed

Please help me out from this issue and if possible then let me know how only migrate only orders SQL way, programmatically and any other way.

Thanks!

Comment: Migrate only orders  from SQL from m1 or m2 database ?

Comment: @HafizArslan Yes. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate only orders from the M1.

> config.xml

```
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>

    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>

    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>

    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
```

Run below command

```
php bin/magento migrate:data vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.1.0/config.xml
```

You can get such issues in the migration like:

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '77-10' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'

Empty these tables to fix issues. You can figure out tables name like this (Note the initials):

> 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID' = catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity

Reference:

> [How to migrate only orders with Data Migration Tool?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173537/how-to-migrate-only-orders-with-data-migration-tool)

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: I followed your steps. But now my process are killed. I think it will require more resource for MySQL. Let me increase it and test it then I will let you know. Thanks for your support.

Comment: form M1 to M2 this process is best only for orders data

Answer (score 0):

> mysqldump -u root -p  sales_invoice sales_invoice_comment
>   sales_invoice_grid sales_invoice_item sales_invoiced_aggregated
>   sales_invoiced_aggregated_order sales_order sales_order_address
>   sales_order_aggregated_created sales_order_aggregated_updated
>   sales_order_grid sales_order_item sales_order_payment
>   sales_order_status sales_order_status_history sales_order_status_state
>   sales_order_tax sales_order_tax_item sales_shipment_item
>   sales_shipping_aggregated sales_shipping_aggregated_order > orders.sql

All Orders Data In This Table :-

```
sales_invoice
sales_invoice_comment
sales_invoice_grid
sales_invoice_item
sales_invoiced_aggregated
sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
sales_order
sales_order_address
sales_order_aggregated_created
sales_order_aggregated_updated
sales_order_grid
sales_order_item
sales_order_payment
sales_order_status
sales_order_status_history
sales_order_status_state
sales_order_tax
sales_order_tax_item
sales_shipment_item
sales_shipping_aggregated
sales_shipping_aggregated_order
```

Comment: Hi, I want to orders fom M1 to M2.