# Migrating Orders from magento1 to magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, migration

I migrated all my products and categories from magento 1 to 2. I need logic to migrate orders which are placed by the customers . Can someone help me please.

Comment: May i know what tutorial you following for upgrade  from magento 1 to 2? @Amol Bhandari SJ

Comment: Check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289449/magento2-3-2-during-data-migration-i-got-only-enties-mismatch-error-only-order/289468#289468

Comment: @Gem not using any documentation. I wanted logic as i was done with rest of the things migration using csv export and then import.

Comment: thanks @Sumit will follow the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade Your Magento version first, you can follow this document: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html

After completely upgraded, you need to find experienced migration experts to help you migrate data such as products, categories and orders from your old store on Magento 1 to Magento 2 smoothly, quickly and safely. This solution save you a lot of time and effort.