# Need suggestion regarding Data migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration

I have done data migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2 using data migration tool.
The site is still not launched and my Magento 1 site is still live.
Now my client has some requirements, for which i want some suggestion.

1. I want to again migrate only products from Magento 1 to Magento 2(The existing site where migration was done earlier)
2. I want to make changes into the products pricing, attributes etc etc in Magento 2.
3. After doing that i want to migrate only orders and customers into Magento 2 existing site. No product migration needed again.
4. Then , this site will be launched.
   I want to work on the same magento 2 environment . I don't want to again setup fresh magento for all these migration.

Is this scenario feasible. If yes, then how?
Is there an extension that will help me in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer yes, it's possible.
In the company I work I did something like that, I just didn't migrate the products they were already migrated, I just did the migration of orders and customers and it was a pain not to mess up everything else.
There was many changes done in Magento 2 after the migration? if not I advise doing the whole migration again. If yes, it's possible but you'll need to search and do a trial error with the map.xml ignoring tables.
Can't help much in this part of importing products but I still have the map.xml and the config.xml that I used to import just the orders or just the customers if it could be any help.

About the extension, I searched but didn't find anything that could catch my eye with a reasonable price, might be wrong though.


Remember always backup everything.

Hope it helps in anyway :D

Comment: So you did the migration of orders and customers on the existing M2 site? or fresh installed site?

Comment: There was a first migration of everything when the site was fresh after a lot time that M2 was being prepared, to go live it was needed the new customers and orders that kept coming to the old M1, so what I did was delete all orders and customer of the already existing M2 site, and import everything from M1, keep in mind that I had no new customers or orders in the M2 that's why I deleted everything it was easier

Comment: Yes, that's what i want. Can you share in detail how did you do the import of orders and customers from M1 to M2?

Comment: Yes ofc I saved almost everything that I used, but they are some long files, how do you prefer for me to send you them?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/467#issuecomment-627912182 Oh yeah I wrote this, not very detailed it kinda depends on the case but might help, if you need the full code of the files let me know

Comment: Can you help me in this?

Comment: Hey, sure I can try but for me it was tricky, following the steps you mentioned in the question, which one are you at now? or it's other?

Comment: I followed this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173537/how-to-migrate-only-orders-with-data-migration-tool/178999 but now around 300 products got deleted and site is messed up

Comment: I advise you always have a database backup on doing this, it's kinda a trial and error, what I did was importing orders and customers separately, tried to import and checked what it imported and wasn't supposed to, then I added that to the ignore. I have the config.xml and map.xml I used saved, I can send them to you but depending on the extensions you have might have some differences I guess

Comment: Please send................

Comment: Can you send me some contact I can send the files to?

Comment: email me on nafisaynafar@gmail.com

Comment: Waiting for the files.....

Comment: I've already sent you to that email

Comment: Thank you @RuiSilva